# Session Problem

Tags: java, servlets

The 
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
and 
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
both creates a new session if there is none present.

My problem is that i want to invalidate() the session if its allready present and then create a new one.

I that possible ..i mean is there any way out to achieve this..??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); // Will not create a new session.
if(session!=null)
{
   session.invalidate();
}
session = request.getSession(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

first kill your old session

```
session.invalidate();
```

and after that reopen it with

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

dont work?

Answer (score 2):

First do a `session.invalidate();` and if necessary then do a `response.sendRedirect("url");` to an `url` where in you can just do `request.getSession();` to get a new session.

Note that this approach is not guaranteed to work in a JSP file, simply because the response is in most cases *already* committed (so that the container cannot set the new value of the `jsessionid` cookie in the response header). You really need to do this in a Servlet or Filter.

That said, why exactly do you want to invalidate the session and then immediately get a new session all in the same request? This sounds like a workaround for a certain problem for which there may be better solutions.